# Android app error: W/ResourceType( 8276): ResXMLTree_node header size 0 is too small

Tags: android, build

This is a working android app that I pulled down from subversion and fired up in Eclipse ADT. I am getting this error:

W/ResourceType( 8276): ResXMLTree_node header size 0 is too small.

I am not sure what it means or where to begin to debug this. This error is appearing in my console window within Eclipse.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me, I was given this error from a character I had accidentally entered into my xml editor. Unfortunately Eclipse often does not highlight the file or line with a red x so it can take forever to track the error down.

If you use source control look through all the xml files you have changed and make sure that none of them have any xml formatting errors.

You can use a tool like this to validate each of the xml files that you are concerned about:
http://xmlwrench.com/online/

NOTE: if you add an extra character at the end of a line these validator tools will not catch it.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in the generated R.java file to see if there is a line highlighted with an error.

For me gen/R.java showed that one of my drawables had an illegal name (it started with a number).

Answer (score 0):

It should be caused by eclipse encoding. You can check this by 
window -> preference ->Content Types ->Text ->xml

Please make sure it is encoded as utf-8